# Binning and plotting geospatial data in python

Tags: python, mapping, geospatial

I am new to geospatial mapping of data in python and would like to visualise my data binned to 1 x 1 degree grids. I have my data in 3 seperate arrays e.g.

`variable_lats:  [ 20.099339  20.142488  20.101004 ... -38.988274 -38.988274 -38.9924  ]`

`variable_lons:  [280.017    279.97015  280.03192  ...  22.829168  22.829168  22.834965]`

`variable_values:  [ 6.388523   6.317164   6.3859496 ... 20.035767  19.707344  19.379091 ]`

I am interested in colour scaling each grid box depending on the density (number of data points) in each grid box.

Any help is appreciated.

thanks

[gridded binned data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OkKll.png)

Comment: I would do like this. Make grid-matrix with numpy and count how many data is each grid cell. Then plot [heatmap with matplotlib](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/images_contours_and_fields/image_annotated_heatmap.html).

Comment: Thanks Shimo, I should have mentioned that my lats/lons data are not monotonic ie. not ordered (values go up and down) and there are also duplicate values since these are the satellite tracking data for the variable of interest. what I am really after is a map like seen in attached (gridded binned data) image

Comment: I think I'm following your desired results. Please try answer example.

Answer (score 0):

When used numpy matrix, plot will be like this. Note that points are only 6 for this example. Then you can modify with matplotlib syntax.

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

# matrix which have 1x1 degree
# matrix_denx[0][0] is count of area lat 89 to 90, long 0 to 1
matrix_dens = np.zeros((180, 360))

variable_lats = [20.099339, 20.142488, 20.101004, -38.988274, -38.988274, -38.9924]

variable_lons = [280.017, 279.97015, 280.03192, 22.829168, 22.829168, 22.834965]

for x, y in zip(variable_lons, variable_lats):

    x_ind = int(np.floor(x))
    y_ind = int(90 - np.floor(y))

    # set value for x_ind, y_ind. += 1 for count.
    matrix_dens[y_ind][x_ind] += 1

# heatmap
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
im = ax.imshow(matrix_dens, cmap="YlGnBu")
plt.show()
```

[image]